# Issue with adding custom fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, xcode5

Okay, so I'm trying to a custom font into an iOS 7 application

I've added the .ttf file into the "Supporting Files" Folder, I've added a new key which has the .ttf file specified, the .ttf file is in the "Copy Bundle Resources" area under "Build Phases" and in my *.m file I have this code... `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Minecrafter_3" size:12];` By the way the "Minecrafter_3" bit is the name before the .ttf of my font.

Then I go into my main.storyboard, highlight the text in my label that I want to be that certain font, I go into the "Fonts" drop down menu and the font is not there, all that is there is the default fonts, with the "Custom" font. I tried using the "Custom" font but all it is, is "Helvetica Neue", which is not my font. I know that this is really long but I've been stuck on this for around 1 week now. Please help me!!!

Comment: `fontWithName:` doesn't need the file name, but the Name of the Fontfamily (and the specific style information).

Comment: @lootsch sorry I am quite new to xCode, could you tell me how to fix my errors.

Comment: open the ttf file on your system, and look for the font name. If you found it, replace `@"Minecrafter_3"` with the font name.

Comment: @lootsch I've opened the .ttf file on my computer this is what I get... http://tinypic.com/r/28i20j7/8 (screenshot) All I can see is at the top it said MineCrafter3 I've replaced @"Minecrafter_3" with @"MineCrafter3" & it still dosent work, any help? Also the style is Regular

Comment: Look at @Thukaram's answer. This should help and check if your font is installed properly.

Comment: If someone's answer solved your issue don't forget to upvote and mark top answer the answer that solved you issue. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved it and those that took the time to answer deserve the rep points.

Answer (score 2):

first You can check your font added to your project or not by using the below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"      Sub names: %@", name);
    }
 }
}
```

for example CourierNew is our font. I declared like this

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"CourierNew" size:40.0f];
```

but actually this is not a font name.

```
Courier New // this one cannot use like font name
//below are font names
       CourierNewPSMT
       CourierNewPS-BoldMT
       CourierNewPS-ItalicMT
       CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT
```

we have to give sub names like this

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"CourierNewPSMT" size:40.0f];
```

Now it should work.

Comment: first of all I have copied and pasted the first bit of code (NSSTRING*, etc), and I'm getting an error saying Expected Identifier or '(' on the first line of code, any thoughts?

Comment: i think some where your not closed the ) check once

Comment: no it's an error on the first line & my code is this....      for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])   Also this is the ONLY line of code in the whole project.

Comment: error is showing for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]) at this line, that's ok but can you check once above lines some where you use open bracket "(" but not yet closed.

Comment: No, look, http://tinypic.com/r/20879er/8  there is absolutely no other code in the entire project that could have caused this, look at the screenshot above /\

Comment: @123ang ... you didn't put your code inside the implementation of the file

Comment: @123ang also see my answer, you missed a phase in the font adding process

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to add the font file to the plist under "Fonts provided by application"

Check out this step by step tutorial:

http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

The previous comments where correct about opening the font file to find the name of the font family, not the file name to use here:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Minecrafter_3" size:12];
```